# Turning Off Infinite Scroll

Tags: wordpress, infinite-scroll

I'm working on: https://holisticharmonyinhc.com/ via Wordpress

On the Single Post view, when you scroll all the way to the bottom, it automatically loads the next post (resulting in two full posts on the same page). I would like to turn off this feature, however I do not see any option in my Dashboard. Assuming it can be done with code but I've tried a few visibility options and nothing seems to be working. Any ideas?

I'm not positive what coding is needed for me to provide, but happy to provide anything requested. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you using  *Look: A Fashion & Beauty News, Magazine & Blog WordPress Theme*.

from dashboard > **Look Options** > **Single Options** > Infinite load post then turn it off.

Comment: Thanks so much! I looked all over and could not find this option. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Glad it's fixed. :)